# How to make an Ajax call and then, onSuccess do a non Ajax call in React/Redux?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

```
  export const abc = ( name ) => ({
    [POST_API]: {
      endpoint: '/webapi/v1/',
      types: [ABC_REQUEST, ABC_SUCCESS, ABC_FAILURE],
      onSuccess: (response) => { },
    },
```

I have used redux-api-middleware package for the above code, I want to make a HttpRequest on onSuccess.

Comment: please provide more context

Comment: I need to make a post call with payload as the response data received on success of the ajax call. Further, my post call is a non ajax call.

Comment: Did you try calling a function directly in your `{ }` of your **onSuccess** and making the call in that said function? `onSuccess: (response) => {this.myNonAjaxCall(response)},`. This way, the function will only trigger if your POST is successful.

Comment: How to achieve the same in Redux